# Foundation 5 Sass Creates Empty Project Folder

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm following the guide over [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) to install Foundation with Sass. I've got Git, Ruby and Node.js installed. I also believe Bower is installed correctly because when I type `bower help` into the command line I get information on its command.

When I try to install Foundation with `gem install foundation` I get this error:

```
Fetching: foundation-1.0.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/foundation-1.0.4/.gitignore
```

If I then try adding `sudo` to the beginning of that command it seems to install just fine. Is this the correct way to do this?

Then when I enter `foundation new test-project` it creates that directory and seems to create those files, but when I go into the "test-project" folder it's empty.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like it with a problem with my git install. I uninstalled git and installed the latest version, and that seemed to do the trick. That folder is now populated with the Foundation files and I can get to work!